# Prevent windows from assigning drive letters to removable drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a USB drive with multiple partitions on it that will be moved around to multiple computers. I want to be able to hide all but the first partition from all the computers I use it on. I have tried using various utilities to add the "hidden" flag to the partitions, but it appears that Windows based operating systems ignore this flag on removable devices. I have also tried using Disk Management to remove the drive letters from the partitions, but those drive letters are computer specific, and are not assigned (or not assigned) the same drive letters in another computer.

I was wondering if this is even possible, and if so, how would you achieve this?

Comment: Obviously one way would be to use a file system that Windows doesn’t natively support.  However, you do risk a user, accidentally formatting the the drive when prompted.  These computers connected to a active directory domain?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using:

- [diskpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) (allow scripting)

[image]

- [Disk management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management) (manually)

[image]